# How do I prepare a file to flash my phone with

Tags: android, android-source

I want to create an image for the Arm chip and deploy it on my Samsung Note 3. I have a compiled copy of

the Samsung source. I added another module to this copy for added functionality. I then downloaded a copy

of the stock firmware, which I have used a number of times to flash my phone. I took the boot.img file of

the stock firmware split it open with a tool online, and replaced the zImage with the zImage that I got

from compiling my source. After several attempts, I seem to be able to create a complete tar.md5 file of

everything in the directory of modified stock source. When I flash the phone with this file using Odin,

the file goes in fine, but the phone is stuck in download mode. I am trying to figure out the main cause

of phone going into download mode, and is the root cause one of packing the files incorrectly or did I not

include a file that is required? Here is what I did to create the tar file with md5 authentication:

I created the tar file:
tar -H ustar -c aboot.mbn sbl1.mbn rpm.mbn tz.mbn sdi.mbn NON-HLOS.bin boot.img recovery.img

system.img.ext4 cache.img.ext4 modem.bin > tarfile.tar

cp tarfile.tar tarfile.tar.md5
md5sum tarfile.tar >> tarfile.tar.md5

I then tried to do a sanity check by comparing the file with a tar archive in an image I have used to

flash my phone with using the file command, and here is what I get ( note: I put my results in the

/expermental directory and the unpacked validated tar file in /originalstck/originaltarfile directory ) (

Note also that the file called tarfile below is the result of packing my files vs.

N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.md5 is what was in the validated stock rom ) :

```
@ubuntu:~/expermental_stock$ file *
aboot.mbn:                                           Hitachi SH big-endian COFF object, not     stripped
boot.img:                                            data
cache.img.ext4:                                      data
info:                                                ASCII text
initramfs.cpio.gz:                                   gzip compressed data, from Unix
modem.bin:                                           x86 boot sector
N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.md5: POSIX tar archive
N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_SPR.zip:                   Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
NON-HLOS.bin:                                        x86 boot sector
recovery.img:                                        data
rpm.mbn:                                             ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 
(SYSV), statically linked, stripped
sbl1.mbn:                                            data
sdi.mbn:                                             ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 
(SYSV), statically linked, stripped
SS_DL.dll:                                           PE32 executable (DLL) (GUI) Intel     80386, for MS 
Windows
system.img.ext4:                                     data
tarfile.tar:                                         POSIX tar archive (GNU)
tz.mbn:                                              ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5     version 1 

(SYSV), statically linked, stripped
zImage:                                              Linux kernel ARM boot executable  zImage (little-

endian)

file ~/originalstock/originaltarfile/*
/aboot.mbn:                                           Hitachi SH big-endian COFF object,    not stripped
/boot.img:                                            data
/cache.img.ext4:                                      data
/modem.bin:                                           x86 boot sector
/N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.md5: POSIX tar archive
/NON-HLOS.bin:                                        x86 boot sector
/recovery.img:                                        data
/rpm.mbn:                                             ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM,  EABI5 version 1 

(SYSV), statically linked, stripped
/sbl1.mbn:                                            data
/sdi.mbn:                                             ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM,   EABI5 version 1 

(SYSV), statically linked, stripped
/system.img.ext4:                                     data
/tz.mbn:                                              ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM,  EABI5 version 1 
(SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

( Note: Here tarfile.tar is the file I made, and I am comparing it with the original tar file that came with the stock rom, which is called N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.md5.) There are two things that concern me with the above output as I am comparing tarfile.tar in /experimentalstock directory with N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.md5 file in the originalstock/originaltarfile dirctory. 1- tarfile.tar is smaller. I added more modules to the source. But that may be explained by the source I started from. I did compare the boot.img files, and the one I created by adding my zImage to it is larger than the one that came with stock rom. I started from the Samsung source code which may not contain the telecom provider's files. 2- My other concern is the output associated with the file command; for tar.file I get: POSIX tar archive (GNU) and for N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.md5 I get POSIX tar archive. Is there a difference between the GNU version vs. whatever is the default format?

My other question is how can see what is going on during the boot when I push my image to the phone? Is there some way I can save the logs on a phone that is unrooted?

According to one of the online sources I used to get this far, I also need to or may include kernel modules. As far as I remember these files have a km extension? I did a search in my Kernel's directory, and do not see any files with this extension:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ locate -r '^/home/user/androidkernel3/.*.km$'
/home/user/androidkernel3/arch/arm/mvp/commkm
/home/user/androidkernel3/arch/arm/mvp/mvpkm
/home/user/androidkernel3/arch/arm/mvp/oektestkm
/home/user/androidkernel3/arch/arm/mvp/pvtcpkm
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Sean

Comment: This is in fact a software development question - the poster is trying to install and run their freshly compiled program.  That said program is an operating system in no way makes the question off topic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you were being ***really*** picky, I'd say the Android Stack Exchange could be a better place: http://android.stackexchange.com/. However as you said, it's a software development question and belongs here, ***however the users of the Android Stack Exchange may be able to supply more help in this instance***.

Comment: @cybermonkey My question is more related to native development for the arm chip; not so much Android development. I did not use a single line of java. All of the above has been done with GNU make.

Comment: @cybermonkey This would not actually be an appropriate question for the Android site; at the root, it's all about how the app is packaged for deployment.

Comment: Unless you have already unlocked the bootloader I doubt this is going to work.

I would expect that the Note 3 will have a locked bootloader, which is not going to boot your custom kernel as it won't have been signed by Samsung's relevant keys.

When you flash the "stock" firmware images from Samsung, they will have been appropriately signed, hence why they work and why your modified ones won't.